# How to render interactive Dash - Plotly using Django (REST framework)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm currently working with generating dashboards. While I understand I can add plotly dash in django templates. I don't seems to understand to use it in a REST framework. I want to know if it is possible to return an 'url' to the front end and on accessing that url - the plotly dash is displayed. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Hey! Take a look at this code: https://github.com/justdjango/My_Dashboard/blob/master/finance/as_dash.py

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot. It was truly helpful.